# Postfix; POST email to URL

Tags: postfix

How do you configure Postfix to forward received mail to a URL using a POST request?

For instance, let Postfix POST the mail to a REST API (i.e. `http://example.com/api/mails`).

The username (and possibly password, though this would already have been checked during authentication) used to authenticate should also be included the POST data in order to distinguish between users.

Comment: Write an application to post messages to your API.  Then redirect all messages to a user, and write a `.forward` for said user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postfix doesn't have REST capabilities built-in, so one will need to write the script in a different language.  You'll have to configure the script as a transport mechanism in your `/etc/postfix/master.cf` file and configure postfix to use that transport mechanism via transport maps (e.g. `transport_maps`).

I'm not aware of any way the password used for SASL authentication could be forwarded to a script, so you'd have to find an alternative there.

Comment: Thanks! According to http://www.postfix.org/pipe.8.html, the username during authentication can be passed using `${sasl_username}`. Since this username is already authenticated by the time the script would recieve it, I think I can safely skip the password as long as I use some other (static) credentials to communicate with the REST API.